# matplotlib wrong line placement mlines.Line2D

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to get a simple lineplot, between point pairs.
This function is supposed to add each line seperately to the plot.

```
def newline(p1, p2):
   ax = plt.gca()
   l = mlines.Line2D(p1, p2)
   ax.add_line(l)
   return l
```

The input point pairs, look like this:

```
[19, 11], [65, 56]
[19, 11], [52, 31]
[65, 56], [52, 31]
```

Unfortunately something seems to go wrong, as the plot looks like this:
[image: faulty line placement]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which might be relevant for others:

Line2D takes the x values and the y values as the two arguments

A little modification of the code solves the problem:

```
def newline(p1, p2):
   ax = plt.gca()
   l = mlines.Line2D([p1[0], p2[0]], [p1[1], p2[1]])
   ax.add_line(l)
   return l
```